# de Broglie hypothesis

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Bohr's model assumes that atomic orbitals are integral multiple of electrons de Broglie hypothesis.

why is it true and what does it physically signifies ?

I was interpreting it as the the orbitals r formed when the de Broglie wave interferes constructively with itself..... $2\pi r = n\lambda$ , $\lambda$---wavelength, n=integer...r=orbital radius.......the orbital is not formed if interferes destructively(which is reasonable)....but why is intermediate condition are also forbidden ?

Comment: Suggestion: your question would have a lot more appeal if it were written using the equation editor (it is similar to LaTeX). It will be more readable and easy to understand.

Comment: Hi watson, I have [removed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/311629/revisions) the second half of your question as it is unrelated to the first half and only serves here as a distraction, but feel free to [ask it as a separate question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: hey i agree but i couldn't put the other qsn independently i dont know why it was giving some error report....imean is there any  threshold "no. of word" below which qsns can't be asked??

Comment: “some error” – Well, what did the error message say? And yes, there is some threshold, I believe.

Comment: What is "it" in the question "why is it true"? the deBroglie hypothesis, the Bohr model, integral multiple of electrons (?).  The Bohr model is not true. It has agreement with the energies, but is woefully lacking in angular momentum values. Bohr model has some value historically and shows how science make progress via multiple attempts.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Bohr model “is true” because it gives the transition energies of the hydrogen atom to very good precision. It is not perfectly correct because one has to include quantum field theory corrections to it as well, but that is not really a concern for your question.

   Intermediate multiples of wavelengths are forbidden because there is no constructive interference. Imagine the wave going round and round. At a fixed point, it will have a different amplitude on each “orbit”. However, since the Hamiltonian does not explicitly depend on time, the solution to the Schrödinger equation must factor and one has to have a stationary solution. Only a stationary wave is a solution, and you only get those with a clean integer multiple.
2. I do not really understand what you mean with “the work”. There is no change in energy for an electron in a stationary orbital around a nucleus. It is an important postulate that there is no Bremsstrahlung emitted by the electron as the classical (non-quantum) theory would say. A bar magnet picking something up is not doing work because the potential energy is lowered when the ferromagnetic object is closer to the magnet.

   You can indeed let electrons rotate in an electric field, see the [Teltron tube experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teltron_tube). For an atom, this is not that feasible though: First, you would have Bremsstrahlung and the electron would spiral into the center. Then the nucleus would have to create a homogeneous magnetic field around itself to bind the electron. The atom would no longer be rotationally symmetric, it would have one special direction, parallel to the magnetic field. This would fail to explain chemistry. For instance the shape of molecules like $\mathrm{H_2O}$ or $\mathrm{CH_4}$ can be nicely explained with [VSEPR model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSEPR_theory). For that, however, you need to have spherically symmetric atoms to make the right hybrid orbitals.

Comment: hmm..i understand yor point ......your logic was that...since for a steady state situation Hamiltonian is time independent ...any fractional superposition of debroglie wavelength will cause time dependency.....but why is it has 2 b a steady state?? if the amplitude is time dependent then would it violate any thin?? in e.m wave we can easily have time dependent amplitude...

Comment: and i couldn't understand a bit of your 2nd ans could u be a bit more simplier plz??

Comment: What level of physics classes do you have, like which year of school/college/university are you in? Since I did not understand your question and was just guessing what it could have been and wrote an answer to that. So please take some minutes to write out your question in full sentences and specify everything that you know and don't know. Then people on this site will have a fair chance of giving you an understandable answer, since they know where you currently are with your understanding.

Comment: ok i am doing b.sc 2nd year....i know magnetostat in classical level nd a bit of old quantum mech......no idea abou Bremsstrahlung.......apart from that i didn't understand the term.."A bar magnet picking something up is not doing work because the potential energy is lowered ...."